# android studio emulator dose not work with error code -1073741819

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

my android studio emulator doesn't work and just tel me:
**Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)**
any body can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(0xC0000005)` is due ram issues, i would recommend restart android studio, close your emulator and create a new AVD with more RAM. Also, if the android emulator from android studio does not work well, you can try genymotion free, it works smooth and it works with virtual box, so it should work on any system

Comment: i try steps but no answer ! but thanks to you for help :) , i use nox and it is working well